# Determining W subspace of R^3

Tags: vector-spaces

I would like to ask if my answer for the question is correct or not. If not what kind of path should watch in order to find the answer. If it is correct how can I further improve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztAiw.jpg)

Comment: Much simpler: does that set contain the zero vector?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't. There for it is not a subspace of R^3.

Comment: And in the second questions it asks if W is a subspace of M3x3 (with the standard operations of matrix addition and scalar multiplication. I do not really understand the definitions as M3x3. Does that mean a 3x3 matrix? And if so wouldn't it be R^3?

Comment: Yes, $\;M_{3\times3}\;$ is the vector space of all square matrices of order $\;3\;$ over some (known or given) field, and no: it is not $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ at all.

Comment: I have tried to write down a matrix of M3x3 as kind of a span of W but it did not led me to a solution. And in addition it gives that M3x3 is not invertible therefore we know that the determinant!=0. Do I have to find the determinant by writing a matrix as I said above and find values for it? I am stuck and don't know clearly how to move on.

Comment: The $\;W\;$ that was in your link is a subset of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ , *not of* $\;M_{3\times3}\;$ , therefore it can't possibly be subspace of $\;M_{3\times3}\;$ .